# Create visuals in python?

Tags: python

Me and my friend are making a small, very text-based adventure/fantasy game. The combat is the turn-taking style you see in games like Pokemon or Final Fantasy, but it's played as a linear visual novel with multiple paths. Right now we're just working on a combat algorithm and other basics, but when we actually get to designing the world I'm not sure if there's a way to create visuals with python or if I have to couple it with another code that works with python in order to do this. If so, how do I "couple", or whatever the term is, this code with the python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a game of the type you describe written in Python, [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org) is probably a good choice. You can open up a window and start doing graphics from within your Python program.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Would you mind me asking what this is exactly though?

Comment: It's explained on the web site better than I could explain it: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/about